# LinQ: How to Write single Query to retrieve records while passing List/string collection in efficient way?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i have written Linq query to retrieve records more quick way. But it take more time to retrieve while passing local collection values to Linq query:

Here i working LinQ query with entity framework. i need to get forumthread based on all platformId which passed as String Collection here

goal: How we can retrieve records with matched id's collection  in a single linQ query with more efficient way?
ex: Slow Execution Query:

```
public void GetThreadCollection(string[] platformid)
{
    using (SupportEntity support=new SupportEntity())
    {
        var ThreadCollection = (from platid in platformid
                                from thread in support.ForumThread
                                from platform in support.Platforms
                                where platid == thread.Platformid &&
                                      platform.PlatformId==platid
                                select new
                                {
                                    ThreadId = thread.threadid,
                                    Title = thread.Title,
                                    description = thread.desc,
                                    platformName = platform.platformName
                                }).ToList();                        
    }
}
```

ex: Then i rewritten the code to avoid slow execution time by sending individual platform id to retrieve records using iteration : for each: but this also take some more less time previous one. but not efficient.

ex:

```
public function(string[] platformId)
{
    foreach(platid in platformId)
    {
        using (SupportEntity support = new SupportEntity())
        {    
            var Threads = (from thread in support.ForumThread
                           from platform in support.Platforms
                           where platid == thread.Platformid &&
                                 platform.PlatformId == platid
                           select new
                           {
                               ThreadId = thread.threadid,
                               Title = thread.Title,
                               description = thread.desc,
                               platformName = platform.platformName
                           }).ToList();

            ThreadCollection.AddRange(threads);                     
        }
    }      
}
```

Can you please suggest , How to get the write single query to retrieve records more efficient in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass in a bunch of Id's to a query to compare to Id's in the database, typically you would use a `Contains` call instead of looping through it (which will cause another query for each iteration of the loop, and will be quite slow). I can't quite gather how it would fit into your Entities since I'm not sure how the `using (SupportEntity support = new SupportEntity())` portion would work, but here's a simple example:

```
public IEnumerable<Car> GetCarsMatchingIds(IEnumerable<int> carIds)
{
    using(var dealershipContext = new DealershipContext())
    {
        return dealershipContext.Cars.Where(c => carIds.Contains(c.Id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what Ocelot said: `Contains` will translate directly into the equivalent test in SQL (something like `where id in (1, 2, 3)`) and be most efficient. Second, the Platform entity should have a navigation property of related threads. You should be able to reduce the query to something like this:

```
from platform in support.Platforms
where platids.Contains(platform.id)
from thread in platform.ForumThreads
select ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. it's working great more efficient.

Comment: Can you please explain why the Linq query process slow when you execute local collection with sql server collection[table]?

Comment: @Anandh Try comparing the SQL that is generated, using ObjectQuery.ToTraceString: `((ObjectQuery)(from ...)).ToTraceString()`